# Understanding「のこと、…」

Tags: grammar, parsing

I need help with this long sentence from the novel. My brain stopped working properly on the second part. The context is a guy was having a chat with a girl who complained about getting approached by many guys. His inner monologue went like this

> 口説かれた回数を愚痴るなど相談相手によっては自虐風自慢と受け取られてもおかしくないところだが、**そこはフラットなスタンスを至上とする俺のこと、妙なバイアスをかけることなく素直に悩みを受け止める。**

I believe the first part can be understood as

> ((口説かれた回数を愚痴るなど) ((相談相手によっては) (自虐風自慢と受け取られてもおかしくない)))ところだが
>
> Complaining about number of times you got approached, depending on who you discuss with, it can be taken as 自虐風自慢. However, ...

I get the general idea but I'm confused how the second part is put together. How 俺のこと works here? Who is doing 妙なバイアスをかける (and to who?) and 悩みを受け止める?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This ～のこと is an uncommon conjunctive usage of こと meaning "since it's ～". It's a friend of [のことだから](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A0%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-koto-dakara-meaning/) and [ことだし/ことですし](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A0%E3%81%97-koto-dashi/). フラットなスタンスを至上とする modifies 俺 as a relative clause.

> そこはフラットなスタンスを至上とする俺の**こと**、
> (But) **since** I am a guy who regards フラットなスタンス as supreme, ...

(Not sure how to translate this フラットなスタンス...basically "attitude to avoid cynical/prejudiced ways of seeing things" or something along those lines.)

**EDIT** Here are some possible variants of saying "since she is who she is", "because it's her":

- 彼女のことだから、また遅刻するだろう。(or ですから～でしょう)
- 彼女のことなので、また遅刻するだろう。(or ですので～でしょう)
- 彼女のことだし、また遅刻するだろう。(or ですし～でしょう)
- 彼女のことだ、また遅刻するだろう。(or です～でしょう)
- 彼女のこと、また遅刻するだろう。