# コトを appears after the verb

Tags: translation, manga, particle-を, reading-comprehension

I came across this sentence in chapter 37 of それでも歩は寄せてくる:

> [image: それでも歩は寄せてくる 第３７局]
>
> うるし：「あぶなー… 寒いとか言ってたら歩のことだ」
> 歩：「オレの学ランをどうぞ」
> うるし：「とか言って私がまた照れちゃうコトを」

Now, what I understand the use of the first こと in which there is an omission of "what about Ayumu" she is talking about but basically she is saying that It would be bad for her to say stuff like I'm cold because it is Ayumu.

But the second こと is marked by を and appears **after** the verb (「照れちゃう」) which makes the whole thing grammatically invalid as far as I understand. While I understand the two as a whole I I'm having an hard time understanding this コト.

Now it may the case of standard Japanese omission but what is the verb that targets this コト(is it the 照れちゃう? One of the 言ってs and is the コト here refers to what Ayumu is saying or to something else?

Thanks!

Comment: The first ことだ means "Since Ayumu is what he is". See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/93649/5010). For the second コト, [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/54677/5010) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This コト simply means a “thing” he would do. The omitted verb is most certainly する.

照れちゃう coming before it is normal. The clause 私がまた照れちゃう modifies コト.

Comment: So what is the connection between とか言って and the rest of it? Is it part of the same sentence of the コト? Such that とか言ってＸコトを(する) where X is 私がまた照れちゃう or is it related to one of the previous sentences and if so to which one?

Comment: @UriGreenberg - It’s part of the same sentence:「オレの学ランをどうぞ」とか言って、私がまた照れちゃうコトを（するにちがいない）。